# Expected reporter error in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have tried for a long time, but I cant solve the following error.

In a turtle I want to change the pcolor, into the pcolor of a patch somewhere else in the field. Example:

```
ask turtles [
  set pcolor (ask patch 0 0 [show pcolor])
]
```

However I just recieve the error "Expected error".

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: if you want to change the colour of all the patches with turtles on them, it is better to ask the relevant patches (something like `ask patches with [ any? turtles-here ]` so that a patch with 5 turtles only get asked once instead of 5 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use

```
ask turtles [
  set pcolor [pcolor] of patch 0 0
  ]
```

It does what I assume you want.